# Cross-platform Linux system update tasks

Tags: bash, apk, yum, apt, dnf

Generally speaking, I'm ok about fully updating all of my systems on a daily basis either from cron or manually. My goal in the following is to have cross-platform code for CentOS or Ubuntu (and ideally also on Alpine and SLES etc) that will do this. A large part of the below was from somewhere else (can't find where) but it was broken and I had to adjust some bits to get this working.

1. The idea is for this to only perform updates if a certain period has passed (here, 24 hours) - am I checking the right files `/var/cache/apt` for Debian/Ubuntu and `/var/cache/dnf/expired_repos.json` for RHEL/Fedora/CentOS? I'm not completely sure as sometimes I think the update should be triggering, so I think something else is updating those files, so I'm curious if there are better files to target?
2. Would you say that I am capturing everything that you would expect to fully update a system (in terms of update / fix-broken / upgrade) and am I doing them in the right order? I *think* I'm covered for Ubuntu, but maybe I'm missing something for CentOS?
3. I'm curious in particular also to make this compatible with Alpine, as that's my goto for docker learning etc, so would like to have it seamlessly update those when I'm messing around with my Alpine WSL instance (SLES less so, but would be a nice to have), i.e., what is the correct way to fully update Alpine, and what file should I test to check for an update time in that distro?

```
MANAGER=
type apt    &> /dev/null && MANAGER=apt    && DISTRO="Debian/Ubuntu"
type yum    &> /dev/null && MANAGER=yum    && DISTRO="RHEL/Fedora/CentOS"
type dnf    &> /dev/null && MANAGER=dnf    && DISTRO="RHEL/Fedora/CentOS"   # $MANAGER=dnf will be default if both dnf and yum are present
type zypper &> /dev/null && MANAGER=zypper && DISTRO="SLES"
type apk    &> /dev/null && MANAGER=apk    && DISTRO="Alpine"

### print_header() will display up to 3 arguments as a simple banner
print_header() {
    printf "\n\n\n####################\n"
    printf "#\n"
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then printf "# $1\n"; fi
    if [ "$2" != "" ]; then printf "# $2\n"; fi
    if [ "$3" != "" ]; then printf "# $3\n"; fi
    printf "#\n"
    printf "####################\n\n"
}

function getLastUpdate()
{
    if [[ $MANAGER == "apt" ]]; then local updateDate="$(stat -c %Y '/var/cache/apt')"; fi   # %Y  time of last data modification, in seconds since Epoch
    if [[ $MANAGER == "dnf" ]]; then local updateDate="$(stat -c %Y '/var/cache/dnf/expired_repos.json')"; fi   # %Y  time of last data modification, in seconds since Epoch
    local nowDate="$(date +'%s')"   # %s seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
    echo $((nowDate - updateDate))  # simple arithmetic with $(( ))
}

function runDistroUpdate()
{
    local updateInterval="${1}"     # An update interval can be specifide as $1, otherwise default to a value below
    local lastUpdate="$(getLastUpdate)"

    if [[ -z "$updateInterval" ]]   # "$(isEmptyString "${updateInterval}")" = 'true'
    then
        updateInterval="$((24 * 60 * 60))"   # Adjust this to how often to do updates, setting to 24 hours in seconds
    fi
    updateIntervalReadable=$(printf '%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $((updateInterval/3600)) $((updateInterval%3600/60)) $((updateInterval%60)))

    if [[ "${lastUpdate}" -gt "${updateInterval}" ]]   # only update if $updateInterval is more than 24 hours
    then
        print_header "apt updates will run as last update was more than ${updateIntervalReadable} ago"
        if [ "$MANAGER" == "apt" ]; then sudo apt --fix-broken install -y; fi   # Check and fix any broken installs, do before and after updates
        if [ "$MANAGER" == "apt" ]; then sudo apt dist-upgrade -y; fi
        if [ "$MANAGER" == "apt" ]; then sudo apt-get update --ignore-missing -y; fi   # Not sure if this is needed
        sudo $MANAGER update -y
        sudo $MANAGER upgrade -y
        sudo $MANAGER install ca-certificates -y
        sudo $MANAGER autoremove -y
        which apt-file &> /dev/null && sudo apt-file update   # update apt-file cache but only if apt-file is installed
        if [ "$MANAGER" == "apt" ]; then sudo apt --fix-broken install -y; fi   # Check and fix any broken installs, do before and after updates
    else
        local lastUpdate="$(date -u -d @"${lastUpdate}" +'%-Hh %-Mm %-Ss')"
        print_header "Skip apt-get update because its last run was ${updateIntervalReadable} ago"
    fi
}

runDistroUpdate
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Pardon me, there was a missing function `print_header` and there was one line that used `exe`, but I've removed that, sorry, does it run now?